# Inputing using from sys import argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I'm studying for my python programming test and I'm going over past exams, and got a bit stuck on this one question. The problem is with inputting arguments using the `sys` library.

My program works but only when I input single length characters. If there are more than two characters between the delimiter(I used a comma),then the program splits it in a way that the rest of the program fails to work.

What my program works for:

```
PS C:\Users\Michal\Desktop> python untitled5.py a,b,c 
Input answer: a,v,c
x:['a', 'b', 'c'] y:['a', 'v', 'c'] lenx:3 leny:3
grade: 3.5
```

What my program should work for:

```
PS C:\Users\Michal\Desktop> python untitled5.py aa,bb,cc
Input answer: aa,cc,dd
x:['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'] y:['aa', 'cc', 'dd'] lenx:6 leny:3
None
```

My code:

```
def grade(key,answer):
    right=[]
    wrong=[]
    if len(x)==len(y):
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if x[i] == y[i]:
                right.append(x[i])        
            else:
                wrong.append(x[i])   
        wynik = len(right)/(len(right)+len(wrong)) *100
        if wynik >= 50 and wynik < 60:
            print('grade: 3')
        elif wynik >= 60 and wynik < 70:
            print ('grade: 3.5')
        elif wynik >= 70 and wynik < 80:
            print ('grade: 4')
        elif wynik >= 80 and wynik < 90:
            print ('grade: 4.5')
        elif wynik >= 90 and wynik <= 100:
            print('grade: 5')
    else:
        print("None")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    x = argv[1]
    x = list(x)
    x[:] = (value for value in x if value != ",")
    y = list(map(str, input('Input answer: ').split(',')))
    #print("x:{} y:{} lenx:{} leny:{}".format(x,y,len(x),len(y)))
    grade(x,y)
```

I have tried doing

```
x = list(map(str, input('Input answer: ',argv[1]).split(',')))
```

but to no avail. Is there a way to input characters (quantity set by the user) directly with a set delimiter?

Comment: You also could take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)...

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do:

```
args = sys.argv[1].split(',')
```

and of course you can choose what delimiter to use.

Comment: Glad that helped!!!, If you find it right you could mark it as right to be helpful for others  with same problem...